# How to append a value in title of HTML tooltip

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a code in HTML like this.

```
<input type="text" 
       id="cableless_plans_limit" 
       class="form-control list-text"
       onkeypress="return isNumber(event,127,1)" 
       placeholder="Plan No"
       data-toggle="tooltip" 
       data-placement="top"
       title="Cableless Plan No should be a integer less than" 
/>
```

and a JavaScript in which "maxCblsPlans" is coming from `database`

```
$('#cableless_plans_limit').attr("title", +response.maxCblsPlans);
```

How can I append this to HTML title so that I can get an output like
when I Click in a text box it should show a   **tooltip**    like

Cableless Plan No should be a integer less than 7 ("**maxCblsPlans**" is 7)

Comment: try `$('#cableless_plans_limit').attr("title", $('#cableless_plans_limit').attr("title") +response.maxCblsPlans);`

Answer (score 3):

By using `$('#cableless_plans_limit').attr("title");` you can get the value of the title parameter.

```
$('#cableless_plans_limit').attr("title",     
   $('#cableless_plans_limit').attr("title") +response.maxCblsPlans);
```

Comment: Not working. Its not appending +response.maxCblsPlans. Only shows "Cableless Plan No should be a integer less than" in the tooltip

Comment: This is however how you append the title. What value do you try to append? please provide a `console.log(response.maxCblsPlans);`

Comment: when I do like this, "Plan No should be an integer less than" is showing in tooltip and '7' is showing as another title.   I need to show  "Plan No should be a integer less than 7" as a single tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the old value into a variable & then append the new value & assign it back

```
var title = $('#cableless_plans_limit').attr("title");
title += response.maxCblsPlans;
$('#cableless_plans_limit').removeAttr("title")
$('#cableless_plans_limit').attr("title", title);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This works as a title.But  My problem is I want to append this 7 to the tooltip tittle. Can you help me?

Comment: @sangeethanair If you assign some data like 7 to title then it will automatically appear in tooltip.

Comment: when I do like this, "Plan No should be an integer less than" is showing in tooltip and '7' is showing as another title.   I need to show  "Plan No should be a integer less than 7" as a single tooltip.

Comment: @sangeethanair I've updated the answer, have a look.